# Showing that node shell is async and mongo shell is not

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, synchronous

So I have a mongodb setup and I have some test data in it. I want to be able to show that the mongo shell runs our script sync and node runs our script async. I have setup the two following js files which I got while doing a Mongo University course. This is really more of a test so that I understand what's going on. I am going to cd into the directory where I have mongo installed using npm and where the scripts are also at. Then I will call these scripts, I will call the `mongoshell.js` using

```
>mongo mongoshell.js
```

and nodeshell.js using:

```
>node nodeshell.js
```

Here are the two scripts:

**mongoshell.js**

```
//Find one document in our collection
var doc = db.allClasses.findOne();

print('before');

//Print the result
printjson(doc);

print('after');
```

And the result I get from running that in the shell is:
[image]

So my thinking here is that the print command is something that would return quicker than the query to mongo. BY placing a before and after print and everything coming out in the right order, it must be synchronous.

Next I have the **nodeshell.js**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db){
    if (err) throw err;

    //Find one document in our collection
    db.collection('allClasses').findOne({}, function(err, doc){
        //Print the result
        console.dir(doc);

        //close the DB
        db.close();
    });
});

setTimeout(function(){
    console.dir("10 Milliseconds!");
}, 10);
setTimeout(function(){
    console.dir("100 Milliseconds!");
}, 100);
```

And the result from the console is:

[image]

My thinking here is that I have determined that mongo usually takes between 10 and 100 milliseconds to return my data. If I put two print commands with timeouts one at 10 ms and one at 100 ms one should fire before the json is returned BECAUSE THE NODE SHELL IS ASYNC and the other should fire after..

**MY QUESTION:
Does this hillbilly test actually show that each of the shells are what they are. Synchronous and Asynchronous? if Yes cool, if not, why?**

Comment: This can't be that hard to answer? At the very lest it must show that the node shell is async because my json returned between my two print commands.. Right? I'm new to Node & Mongo, just want to make sure I understand what is gong on...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and would be better suited to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since there is not really a direct question to be answered. That said, a usual process for async demo's is to issue the statement that outputs last as the first statement to make this clear.

Comment: There is a direct question to be answered? ANd I believe that because this has to do with programming and me as a beginner trying to understand what is going on. It's valid. I may actually be doing something wrong or not understanding how the shell actually works. ANd someone could point out that error or let me know that indeed the answer is yes..I'm not advanced enough to know what the answer is and that is why I turned here.

Comment: So neil, you can't take a stab at this? ANd let me know if you think the code that is written that I execute in the node shell is printing out the way it is because of the fact that it's async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how that trick with timeouts demonstrates the async nature. How about this?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db){
    if (err) throw err;

    //Find one document in our collection
    db.collection('allClasses').findOne({}, function(err, doc){
        console.log("Got the data!")

        //Print the result
        console.dir(doc);

        //close the DB
        db.close();
    });

    console.log("Data is being fetched and I do something else")
});

console.log("Mongo connection is being set up and I do something else")
```

### Output

```
sergio@soviet-russia ‹ master ●● › : ~
[0] % node test.js
Mongo connection is being set up and I do something else
Data is being fetched and I do something else
Got the data!
null
```

Comment: I think this demonstrates it, but for someone else who is doesn't understand async I would think would benefit from seeing things happen out of order. My example runs a function that fetches some data. that data takes somewhere between 10 and 100 ms to return data. So my idea was to run code after the function that returns a message at 10 ms so if it was async it would log before the return data. Then we see the data return and then the message that was timed out at 100ms. To me it was logical that considering the return of each of those items somewhat out of order would be proof IS ASYNC

Comment: I think your examples shows it too, but I don't believe someone who needs to understand how async works would understand since both of those messages would run and then the data would return. TO me that says it's async. But to someone who is new to the idea. I think my example is more illustrative. WIth that said. Im a friggin hillbilly coder at best and what do I know!

Comment: @EricB: well, maybe. I just find it confusing. :)

Comment: What confuses me is the off topic comment and the down vote. I'm just trying to learn here. I think that neil had a good answer he never gave because he was upset that I'm asking this stupid question. Sorry, Very meta .. I Know

Comment: @EricB: here's an idea: make two queries, one fast and one slower. Fire the slower one first and then the fast one. The user, seeing in the console that the fast query printed result first, will figure out that it must be async. :)

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I can create a Json object with 10 times more data than the other and fire the faster one after the slower one.

Comment: If there is a problem can you guys say what it is? I always leave a comment when I downvote. Otherwise how am I expected not to make the same error twice?

Comment: @EricB: I didn't downvote, but I imagine that someone didn't like your screenshots (should've been text instead). Or that this question is asking for opinion (such questions are considered off-topic)

Comment: I know you didnt. You were the only one helpful. I also can't copy in my terminal window. I can't imagine that is why, but you never know. I would never downvote someone for that reason. And if they made a good effort to give me all the details I would definitely not downvote them, I would offer criticism.